# Commons-Daemon procrun binaries missing with prunsrv.exe or prunmgr.exe

Tags: java, windows-services, apache-commons-daemon

I am planning to create windows based service using commons-daemon [procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html) . I downloaded the commons-daemon-1.0.10-bin.zip file from downloads, but when I extracted it, I could not find prunsrv.exe or prunmgr.exe files. I found those were missing in the zip file.. Am I pointing to the right download files?
Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before posting this question iam googling on the same topic, put didnot find any answer, but atlast i found the answer for my question.

**`I came to know that the Commons Daemon project does not provide binaries for these applications. The only binaries available are from the Tomcat project. Tomcat comes with two windows binaries: tomcat5.exe and tomcat5w.exe. It turns out that these are "prunsrv" and "prunmgr"`**

Comment: They are not the binaries for registering services. They are binaries for Tomcat. Does not mean that a user will have to download tomcat to make his app a service

Answer (score 4):

The binaries can be found in another zip file located in a sub-directory on the download site.
currently located here:
http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip

Comment: 404 not found, this link is not more active, please give an updated link if possible

Answer (score 2):

The binaries for the required OS can be obtained [here](http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/)

It will list the binaries under the windows folder.